# How do I transfer specific data from one sheet/tab to another based on specific criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to set up a monthly budget for myself and would like to have my expenditures automatically transfer from my "Shopping List" to their designated locations. For example, TEST Sync to the Synchrony section on its chosen tab.

This is for Google Sheets, I've attempted some query functions along with other filtering functions... no idea if I am on the right track or not

```
=query('Shopping List'!C9:J, "Select Shopping_Date, Shopping_Price, Shopping_Payment WHERE 'Shopping_List'!H9:H = "Citi"",-1)
```

I expected it to transfer data from one tab to the next and just got an error code

Comment: Can you add the exact Error, you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to reference the columns you want to retrieve.
Example:

```
=query('Shopping List'!C9:J, "Select C, D, E WHERE H= 'Citi'",-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY('Shopping List'!C9:J, "select C, E, F where H matches 'Citi'", 1)
```

[image: 0]

**[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16D5QYBaMRozpwHuSPgwCGODtE1E_f39CNz5xV3DOo8k/edit#gid=580060987)**